# field_view_field geofield_map

Tags: entities, location

I'm doing the following

```
field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_geo', 
    array(
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'settings' => 
        array(
            'format_type' => 'geofield_map_map'
        ),
    );
```

`field_geo` is a geofield.
`geofield_map` module is enabled (output is fine for this field in other instances where I am not calling `field_view_field()`

In looking through geofield_map.module, there is every indication in hook_field_formatter_info() that I should be using "geofield_map_map", but I don't get the map output. Anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem ... I was defining the output type in the settings array vs directly in the display array.

```
field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_geo', 
    array(
      'label' => 'hidden',
      'type' => 'geofield_map_map'
    )
);
```

Hope this helps someone else.